# comments in C++ in Sublime Text 2

Tags: c++, comments, sublimetext2

I'm trying to write some C++ in Sublime Text 2. If I begin a line with a double forward slash (//) the text in that line grays out as if it were commented out, but it causes a build error when I compile, so clearly it isn't. If I begin the line with a pound sign (#) that line is commented out but doesn't change in appearance. I want to be able to tell what lines are comments and what lines are actually part of my program. How is this done?

Comment: Did you actually save the file?

Comment: seems that you compile and display 2 different languages...

Comment: Seems like this is not a question about Sublime Text 2 - which is highlighting a C++ comment correctly, but with your compiler.

Comment: what is your compiler ?

Answer (score 3):

In c++ comments look like this

```
// one line comment or
/* comment
   over multiple
   lines */
```

If your compiler is not recognizing these, chances are, it's not compiling c++. This seems even more likely seeing how lines beginning with `#` will be ignored like you'd expected for some other languages (for example python)

**Make sure to check what the "build" button in your IDE actually calls/does.**

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into that. I saved my program with the .cc extension, which I thought would automatically make Sublime Text 2 recognize it as C++, but perhaps not. Do you know how I can ask it what language it thinks its dealing with?

Comment: @user3163638 look at the bottom right corner of ST2 when your file is open. It should say "C++". You can also choose the build system by going to `Toold > Build System`.

Comment: Thanks, I think I've figured it out.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
/*
I am a comment!
I am another comment!
*/
```

I hope this helps.